# Save image to camera roll with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to save a photo with a button to camera roll after user capture a picture with Camera , but  I don't know why my picture doesn't save at photo library !!

Here is my code :

```
-(IBAction)savePhoto{

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img.image,nil, nil, nil);

}

-(IBAction)takePic {

    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    ipc.delegate = self;
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    img.image = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]retain];
    [[picker parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];   
}
```

Variable name `ipc` is `UIImagePickerController` and `img` is `UIIMageView`.

what's my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure you are calling `savePhoto`. Then you can add an assertion to check that the image is not nil:

```
- (IBAction) savePhoto {
    NSParameterAssert(img.image);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img.image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```