# How to move video from application documents directory to camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, avfoundation

hallo,

i have found some iphone-camera-video-saving avfoundation code examples 
over the net (and also im tryin to write my own code but not finished it yet)

such examples process and do save the video (through AVAssetWriter) 
from the camera capture input to file located in documments directory 
(which i assume is the only option?)

but now - i do not even can see files in such directory to check
if my video is there; i think i should move such video file to 
'camera roll', how to do that??

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer to Camera Roll - here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538907/save-image-to-camera-roll-with-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum) that should help.

To see what's in your Documents directory, here's a code snippet:

```
 -(void) dump {

    NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:  @"Documents"];
    NSFileManager *localFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum =
        [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];
    NSError *error=nil;

    NSLog(@" Documents Directory: %@", docsDir);
    NSString *file;
    while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
        NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docsDir,file];
        NSDictionary *attrs = [localFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
        if ( error ) {
            NSLog(@" error - %@", error);
        } else {
          //NSLog(@" file : %@", file);
          NSInteger fsiz = [attrs fileSize];
          NSString *ftyp = [attrs fileType];
          NSDate   *fmod = [attrs fileModificationDate];
          NSLog(@"  %9d : %@ : %@ : %@",  fsiz, file, ftyp, fmod );
         }
     }
    NSLog(@" ======  End Documents Directory ========");
   }
```

Comment: tnx tu you, especially for the snippet - it will be much helpfull - in the link it is about the image not video, [ but indeed now i have UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum - if it works it is what i need :) ]

Comment: (regards because of quoting nabokov, i am ('myself is') 'advanced' nabokov scholar)

Comment: I know almost nothing about Nabokov except that quote, which makes a lot of sense to me.