# Copy downloaded video to camera roll

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

Even though it looks like a simple procedure, it's by now 3 hours I'm trying without success. I am probably missing something really stupid.

So, I have this app downloading videos from the Internet. The videos are correctly stored locally because I can play them providing the local url. But, I can't succeed in copying the videos to the camera roll. Here is what I do:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock videoWriteCompletionBlock =
    ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library %@", newURL.absoluteString);
        }
    };

    NSLog(@"file %@", localPath);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localPath isDirectory:NO];
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url
                                completionBlock:videoWriteCompletionBlock];
```

But the output I get is:

```
2013-07-24 00:13:32.094 App[1716:907] file /var/mobile/Applications/70C18C4E-9F97-4A6A-B63E-1BD19961F010/Documents/downloaded_video.mp4
2013-07-24 00:13:32.374 App[1716:907] Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library (null)
```

And of course the file is not saved in the camera roll. It's a simple mp4, compatible with the device I'm using (i.e. it should be possible to save it).

I honestly have no idea what to do. Any hint will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732074/how-to-move-video-from-application-documents-directory-to-camera-roll

Comment: Have you verified that the video is compatible with the camera roll? What does a call to `videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:` say about the video you're working with?

Comment: I already followed the hint given from @fa7d0 link, with no success. I also dumped the Documents directory, and the file is there.

Comment: With the method suggested by @JoshBuhler I actually get a *NO*.. but it's weird, the container is an mp4, should be possible to save it...

Comment: And anyway, shouldn't the save operation throw an error if it's not compatible?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I may have found a workaround for you. Have you tried an `AVAssetExportSession`?

In the sample below, I built a simple app that has two buttons on the screen. One calls `onSaveBtn:`, which simply grabs the URL of a video I have in my app's resource bundle and saves it to the user's saved photos album. (Though, in my case my videos do return `YES` from `videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:`. I didn't have any videos that don't return otherwise.)

The second button is wired to `onExportBtn:`, which takes the video we want to save, creates an `AVAssetExportSession`, exports the video to a temp directory, and then copies the exported video to the saved photos album. Due to the export time, this method does take longer than a simple copy, but maybe this could be an alternate path - check the results of `videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:`, and if `YES`, copy directly to the album. Otherwise, export the video, then copy.

Without having a video file that doesn't return `NO` to the compatibility call, I'm not 100% sure this would work for you, but it's worth a shot.

You may also want to [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257224/what-video-formats-are-compatible-with-the-assets-library), which explores what video formats are compatible on the device you may be using.

```c
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

- (IBAction)onSaveBtn:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *srcURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"WP_20121214_001" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    [self saveToCameraRoll:srcURL];
}

- (IBAction)onExportBtn:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *srcURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"WP_20121214_001" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    AVAsset *srcAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:srcURL];

    // create an export session
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:srcAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

    // Export the file to a tmp dir
    NSString *fileName = [srcURL lastPathComponent];
    NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSURL *tmpURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[tmpDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];

    exportSession.outputURL = tmpURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{       
        // now copy the tmp file to the camera roll
        switch ([exportSession status]) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                NSLog(@"Export successful");
                [self saveToCameraRoll:exportSession.outputURL];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
}

- (void) saveToCameraRoll:(NSURL *)srcURL
{
    NSLog(@"srcURL: %@", srcURL);

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock videoWriteCompletionBlock =
    ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library %@", newURL.absoluteString);
        }
    };

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:srcURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:srcURL
                                    completionBlock:videoWriteCompletionBlock];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the cool hint and snippet. It's a good tip, I'm gonna try it out and see what happens. Then I'll tell you... thanks!

Comment: ok, at least it made it work for some of the files... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you providing the URL to the block.
I think you need to do this way..

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
       /*notify of completion*/
       NSLog(@"AssetURL: %@",assetURL);
       NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
       if (!error) {
            //video saved

       }else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.domain delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
       }

}];
```

You can change the url here, I have used for the imagePickerController..
See if its helps you..

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I wrote I did in the question?

Comment: Thats exactly what you wrote...But I didnt see the URL path, Where is that path, What you are doing here is , saving one image in camera roll and also in document directory, you are providing the URL path for the document directory, but not for camera roll...

Comment: Well, there is a string named *localPath* that I print (and I've put the output: it shows the path in the Documents directory). Then I turn it into a NSURL and try to save it into the camera roll with the *ALAssetsLibrary* method. I don't think you are supposed to provide the path for the camera roll, and anyway I don't see where I am supposed to specify it...

Comment: I think You should write that in the first block, try not to break the block, It may help..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter answer.

In my case, I've used AFNetworking to download a video from a URL and in the downloadCompletedBlock of the download operation, `responseObject` returns the download file. Logging `responseObject` returns me the full file path of the downloaded video.

If you are using another method to download videos, simply replace `responseObject` with the full file path of your video, probably with the usual `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` method.

Here's the snippet I use to export videos in the application's local file directory to the Camera Roll:

```
NSURL *responseObjectPath = [NSURL URLWithString:responseObject];
// If video is compatible with Camera Roll
if ([[ALAssetsLibrary new] videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:responseObjectPath])
{
    // Export to Camera Roll
    [[ALAssetsLibrary new] writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:responseObjectPath completionBlock:nil];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Incompatible File Type");
}
```

Cheers!